# Using Cheerio to scrape for information

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm using Nodejs with the package Cheerio to collect information on a website, I am struggling to collect the information after iterating through to store the information into an array.

The text I want to collect in this example would be "George Ezra - Wanted On Voyage (LP, Album + CD, Album)"

I am currently iterating through elements with the class "shortcut_navigable" and want to store each title in an array.

[image: HTML elements in the webpage]

So far I have not been able to collect the text with this code example.

```
axios(url)
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(html)
        const articles = []
        $('.shortcut_navigable', html).each(function() {
            const title = $(this).find('a').has('.item_description').text()
            articles.push({
                title,
            })
        })
        console.log(articles)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I would like to be able to store all titles form the element with the class 'item_description_title' inside an array and later on be able to store other information.

Any advice and help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You need to share witch URL to parsing it?

Comment: Probably https://www.discogs.com/sell/release/5840245?ev=rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm guessing your URL correctly, `has` doesn't seem necessary. You can use the class name in `.find()` directly.

Here's an example to get you started:

```js
const axios = require("axios"); // 1.4.0
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "https://www.discogs.com/sell/release/5840245?ev=rb";

axios
  .get(url)
  .then(({data: html}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const data = [...$(".shortcut_navigable")].map(e => ({
      title: $(e).find(".item_description_title").text().trim(),
      seller: $(e).find(".seller_block a").text().trim(),
      price: +$(e).find("[data-pricevalue]").data("pricevalue"),
      shipping: $(e).find(".item_shipping").contents().get(0).data.trim(),
      // ...etc...
    }));
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

As an aside, it's a good idea to post [text, rather than screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Axios and cheerio don't execute JS, so the dev tools shown in your screenshot can be misleading, since it shows elements created dynamically, after page load. `view-source:` provides a better representation of what you're likely to get with axios (or simply print the response body that axios delivers). Luckily, JS doesn't appear to be a factor on this part of the site you're working with at this time, but it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your example, I can now grab the data I wanted.
Thanks you also with posting text rather than screenshots, I'll definitely keep that in mind for next time.